# Is "佳能" the standard translation for "canon" in a religious sense?

Tags: vocabulary

Apparently "巴利佳能" is the translation of "Pali Canon."

When referring to the foundational documents of other theological or philosophical schools, will I be understood if I use the term "佳能"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. `佳能` is only used for the translation for Canon the brand/company name.

There are more than one translation for canon in religious sense based on its different meanings. The standard translation for `Pali Canon` is `巴利文大藏经` ([Wikipedia](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B7%B4%E5%88%A9%E6%96%87%E5%A4%A7%E8%97%8F%E7%B6%93)).

If you are interested in the translations for other meanings, you can find them in a dictionary. Another way to find out is on the Wikipedia [disambiguate page for 'canon'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon), choose the term you're interested in, and click on 中文 on the left to see the Chinese version.

Comment: Just want to add: normal words are translated by meaning, names by sound, but company names are special in that they are translated by sound but also with positive meanings, which are often very clever. For example, Nike the company is `耐克` (durable, overcome) but Nike the goddess is `尼刻` (a straightforward rendering of the Greek pronunciation).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not what you are looking for but `正典` seems to fit your meaning of canon here.

```
汉语大词典
1 正宗典籍。如儒家六经之类。
```

[Wikipedia](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%AD%A3%E5%85%B8) talks of it in a Biblical sense, but as you can see from the entry in HDC it can also refer to other things:

```
正典源自希腊语κανων,kanōn，意为“规则；量尺”，英语为Canon。在基督宗教，因教父时期为了系统化神学内容以回应异端的挑战，乃将整个基督宗教的经典分为正典、次经与伪经三个层级。正典是完全可靠的经典，现在通用的拉丁版圣经便是在这一次的集结中定本。“次经”是一些作者还不能完全确定的作品，次经的内容通常无损于正统神学的内涵，因此仍有参考的价值。最后一个级等的“伪经”便是指那些“次经以外的著名”，内容是一些未能确定真伪的著作。
```

正典 is also listed in ABC E-C Dictionary & 21 Century E-C Dictionary as `canon` [among many others].

What you should keep in mind though is that as NS.X. said above specific writings also have their own specific translations so you might want to check *exactly* what you want to say before you say it.